# How to put the type cursor automatically in a JEditorPane?

Tags: java, swing, focus, cursor, jpanel

After a card panel switch I would like to automatically put the type cursor in a `JEditorPane` located in my new displayed card. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
editorPane.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking to place focus on the editor pane when you switch cards when using a CardLayout. If so, then check out [Card Layout Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/card-layout-focus/) for one approach.

Comment: Would [`RequestFocusListener`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) also work for this use-case?

Comment: @AndrewThompson, Yes and this would be an example of when you don't want to remove the listener, as suggested in the comments :)